# Por que recibo los datos asi ( ---) de HTML AgilityPack a CSharp WindowsForms

Tags: html, c#

estoy teniendo problemas al recibir datos por medio de agility pack, solo quiero recivir los datos.

[image: codigo de la pagina que requiro extraer los datos]

al momento que muestro el dato en mi forms me llega como (---)
solo con esas tres etiquetas.

[image: parte del codigo que utilizo. utilizo el mismo codigo para mostrar alguna otra etiqueta y sin problema la muestra]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra los códigos y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. Tu pregunta, tal como está redactada actualmente, es incomprensible. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Posiblemente estés recibiendo la página sin cargar y por lo tanto el número no está cuando lo lees.